# In Jhipster Project Response JSON giving wrong Date format for ZoneDateTime

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, jhipster

```
public abstract class PrimaryBaseEntity {
@JsonFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
@Column(name = "rejected_date")
private ZonedDateTime rejectedDate;
}

//Extended above class
public class CountryChecker extends PrimaryBaseEntity

in application.yml below property added.

spring:
profiles:
    active: dev
    include: SeperateDatabase,no-liquibase
devtools:
    restart:
        enabled: false
    livereload:
        enabled: false # we use gulp + BrowserSync for livereload
jackson:
    #serialization.indent_output: true
    serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS: false
```

Still response JSON coming with below date format
 "rejectedDate": 1519828549,

This is JHIPSter generated project please tell me what changes we need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try mentioning this in application.properties file

```
spring.jackson.date-format= # Date format string (e.g. yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss)
```

or

you can parse timestamp to "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss" using getter method

```
public abstract class PrimaryBaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "rejected_date")
    private ZonedDateTime rejectedDate;

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");

    public Date getRejectedDate() {
       return formatter.parse(rejectedDate);
    }
}
```

Comment: jackson:
        #serialization.indent_output: true
        #serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps: false
        date-format: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
     Still issue exist after adding this also